# php xpath sibling query

Tags: php, xpath

This is the example of data I'm working with:

```
<div class="category">
    fruit
</div>
<div class="location">
    <a href="/fruit">fruit</a>
</div>
```

How the only things that changes is the link in the second div and I'd like to pull the href portion.

How can I target and extract it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: in XPath, `.` represents the "context node", or the node selected by the preceding path step. To select the `<div class="category"/>` where the text contents of the element are equal to "fruit":

```
/div[@class eq "category"][. eq "fruit"]
  /following-sibling::div[@class eq "location"]/a/@href
```

If the HTML is formatted with whitespace in the text node (as it is in your example), you can use the `contains()` function to match part of the text node:

```
/div[@class eq "category"][contains(., "fruit")]
  /following-sibling::div[@class eq "location"]/a/@href
```

**Original Answer**

You can select that `href` in many different ways. Based on your title, it seems that you are already selecting `div/@class eq "category"`, so you could use the `following-sibling` axis like this:

```
/div[@class eq "category"]/following-sibling::div[@class eq "location"]/a/@href
```

Comment: There are many divs with class="category" and I need to select the one that contains word "fruit". So the content of div determines if i grab it's sibling. How can I do that?

Comment: @Jimbotron I added a couple of ways to select based on the text of the element.